# How to access a level 2 parent (grandparent) behaviour in JADE?

Tags: agents-jade

I am trying to access a grandparent behaviour and its Datastore in JADE. I have a level 3 nested behaviour in the Supervisor agent, as shown in the figure below.[image]

The hierachy is

```
ContractNetResponder->Sequencial->ContractNetInitiator

ContractResponder(blue)->InquireServiceList(white)->Inquire(yellow)
```

I am trying access the the data store of the ContractResponder in the Inquire behaviour. I can access the InquireServiceList behaviour from within the Inquire behave but not the ContractResponder. This is what i have thus far:

```
  InquireServiceList parent= (InquireServiceList) this.getParent();
            System.out.println("1!! Parent ="+parent.getBehaviourName()+" Class ="+parent.getClass());

            ContractNetResponder grandparent= parent.  //I need to get parent here
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this problem was to overide the getParent() method in the parent behaviour and change visibilty from protected to public. This solution was suggest by Arnould Guidat in the jade-development mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Also check root(); method in behaviour to access root behaviour.